# Import records from Excel sheet into SQL Server with validations in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, webforms

I'm just following [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/import-records-from-excel-sheet-to-sql-server-with-validations-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp-1052.aspx) to import records from an Excel sheet into SQL Server with validations.

It's done using Webforms, here I'm trying to do it using asp.net mvc 5

This is the [controller class](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/7Eaen/product-upload-controller-class)

This is the [Viewpage file](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/MM6e9/view-page-to-upload-files)

But here I'm getting following errors

> The name 'uploaddata' does not exist in the current context

Getting this error in  `ImporttoDatatable()` method

> The name 'gvEmployee' does not exist in the current context

Getting this error in  `BindGrid()` method

> 'Page' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Getting this error in  `CheckData()` method

Answer (score 0):

So if you are using MVC5 you should be using Data Annotations on a view model/model for validation. Instead of creating all the methods to do it for you, see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(VS.95).aspx. I also recommend using the open source library DocumentFormat.OpenXml  and the SpreadSheetDocument class for reading in a spreadsheet its much easier

```
 using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("filename", false))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart workSheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
            var sheetData = workSheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>();
        }
```